# JQuery passing arguments for On Change for an item added to DOM via AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have multiple HTML fragments that are inserted into my DOM as the result of AJAX call-backs.

Each of these fragments will contain a text box whose class is "quantity".

What I want to do is to create an "on change" event handler that fires whenever one of these textbox's text value is changed.  However, when that event is fired/handled, I need to know WHICH specific textbox was updated.

Okay, using jQuery, I have the following that fires in my "Lists.initHandlers" method:

```
$(document).on('change', $('#divABC').find(".quantity"), List.quantityChanged);
```

And my "List.quantityChanged" event handler happily fires when I update the quanity.

The problem is that when I reference "this" within the event handler, I get the whole document, and not the element that triggered the event.

I have tried to capture the element using syntax similar to:

```
$(document).on('change', $('#divABC').find(".quantity"), {ctrl: this}, List.quantityChanged);
```

but when I attempt this, the handler is never fired (even when I change the signature to expect an argument).

Any guidance here would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Griff

Comment: shouldn't it just be "#divABC>input.quantity"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $('.quantity').live('change', function(){
        alert('New value: ' + $(this).val());
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this` to your function:

```
$(document).on('change', $('#divABC').find(".quantity"), function () {
    List.quantityChanged(this);
});
```